# Dimension values are not getting updated when updating Catia constraints

Tags: vba, catia

Please check the below code, when I update the product at last, the dimension values are not reflected in fix constraint. Any idea why is it happening so?
but when done manually it is working properly

```
Sub CATMain()

Dim productDocument1 As ProductDocument
Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim product1 As Product
Set product1 = productDocument1.Product

Dim parameters1 As Parameters
Set parameters1 = product1.Parameters

Dim dimension1 As Dimension
Set dimension1 = parameters1.Item("910.837802STR\Constraints\Fix.15\Fix.15\pos_rotx")

dimension1.Value = 3.402

Dim parameters2 As Parameters
Set parameters2 = product1.Parameters

Dim dimension2 As Dimension
Set dimension2 = parameters2.Item("910.837802STR\Constraints\Fix.15\Fix.15\pos_rotz")

dimension2.Value = -37.162

Dim constraints1 As Constraints
Set constraints1 = product1.Connections("CATIAConstraints")

Dim constraint1 As Constraint
Set constraint1 = constraints1.Item("Fix.15")

constraint1.ReferenceType = catCstRefTypeFixInSpace

product1.Update

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the *ReferenceType* to *catCstRefTypeFixInSpace* resets the position of the constraint.
Either remove this line or set this value after updating the assembly/constrain.